# Docker- connetcting AWS DynamoDB with ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, amazon-dynamodb

I want to connect my dynamoDB with ElasticSearch and to achieve that I need to use docker. But I get an error:

[image]

As I understand sth is wrong with elasticSearch host however it works:

[image]

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you have Elasticsearch in a seperate docker container than logstash, then you have to insert the Elasticsearch container IP address or hostname instead of localhost in the configuration, you can find this IP address of the docker container by running:
    `docker inspect <container ID>`